# Can you recover the original vectors that, when summed together, achieved a particular criteria

Tags: linear-algebra, string-manipulation, vector, conditional, character-encoding

I am wondering if it is possible to take the binary strings of length $3$ (tuples) whose sums have weight $2$ (i.e they have $2$ non-zero entries)(binary case, meaning they have two $1$'s entries) $$u \in \text{tuples}$$ $$v \in \text{tuples}$$ $$u + v \in \text{tuples of weight } 2$$
and then recover which original strings ($u,v$) summed together to give a vector of weight $2$?

The following code takes all the possible binary strings of length $3$ (tuples) and then adds every string to every other string (filter). I do this in order to find the positions in which those strings differ (because they are binary strings, a 1 in position i means that both strings differed in the $i^{th}$ position).

I then use the `If[]` function to see which resulting vectors from the filter have weight $2$.

However, what I would like to do would be to find a way to "reverse" this process and figure out which of the original tuples added together to give these vectors of weight 2 (two non-zero entries).

I'm not quite sure how to go about this. If anyone had any ideas, that would be great!

```
tuples=Tuples[{0,1},3]
filter=Flatten[Outer[Mod[Plus[##], 2] &, tuples, tuples, 1], 1]
distance2=If[Total[#] == 2, #, Nothing] & /@ filter
```

Comment: Try `Select[filter, Total[#] == 2 &]` which gives the same result `distance2`

Comment: That is certainly a cleaner way to get distance2, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not create all tuples, it only creates valid tuples.

Note that to get a digits of 0 in the result, the digits in the 2 initial lists must either be both 0 or both 1.

To get a digit of 1, the initial digits must be either 1,0 or 0,1.

With this we may create a function that takes a result list and returns pairs of possible initial lists.

```
getinitial[in_]:= Module[{t},
  t= in /. {0 -> {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}, 1 -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}};
  t = Flatten[Outer[Transpose[{#1, #2, #3}] &, Sequence @@ t, 1], 2]
]
```

We can apply this function on the possible result lists: {0,1,1},{1,0,1},{1,1,0}:

```
getinitial /@ {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like $u+v$ is just `BitXor[u,v]` here, and since `BitXor` is its own inverse another possibility is:

```
sumPoss = Permutations[{1, 1, 0}] // Reverse;
tups = Tuples[{1, 0}, 3];
Outer[Join[{#2, BitXor[#1, #2]}] &, sumPoss, tups, 1] // MatrixForm
```

I reversed the output of `Permutations` to match @DanielHuber's matrix output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do explicitly create all the `{0,1}` 3-tuples, so this may be bad.